# Swiper js and React: How to pass React state when swiping left or right to prev/next slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I am using [Swiper js](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) for my React slider.

I'am looping over an Object and return the Swiper slides.

I have some (filter) buttons as swiper slides, to filter content when selecting/clicking a button (by passing React state).

The active slide (which gets css class `swiper-slide-active` by the swiper api) should always be centered.

That's working fine from the api with the following props:

`centeredSlides` and `slideToClickedSlide`

But when I 'swipe' the slides to left or right, the swiper active slide get centered, but my other logic on the selected button `data-active={true}` is now not in sync with swipers active slide.

How to fix this?

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-state-swiper-8-op0ij8), with an example what I have so far.